# $\sqrt[0]{x}$ indeterminate form?

Tags: calculus, limits, indeterminate-forms

I stumbled across a list of indeterminate forms on Wolfram Alpha. On top of the common ones, plus a few ones like $(-1)^\infty$ that usually aren't mentioned in textbooks but I can make sense of, one captured my attention.
$$\sqrt[0]{x}\hskip1.0cm\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$

I'm trying to figure out why this would be an indeterminate form.

Let $f(x)$ be a function and $g(x) = \frac{1}{x}$.
Then, we have
$$\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)^{g(x)} = \sqrt[0]{f(x)}$$

Such a limit evaluates to $\infty$ for every $f(x)$ greater than $1$, to $1$ for every $f(x)$ constantly equal to $1$, to $0$ for every $f(x)$ smaller than $1$, and is an indeterminate form if $f(x)$ tends to $1$ or $0$.

In other words, I would say that $\sqrt[0]{x} = x^\infty$, the latter not being an indeterminate form for every $x$ but just for some $x$'s.

So is it really correct to say that $\sqrt[0]{x}$ is an indeterminate form $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Can you provide a link to this information ?

Comment: "In other words, I would say.....". Now that statement doesn't feel good, in particular when the zero is approached from the negative side.

Comment: @YvesDaoust https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%2F0 this shows up under the "Other indeterminate forms" section by clicking "More forms." I'm sorry, I couldn't find a mention to it anywhere else but it does show up there.

Comment: Beware that $\frac10=\pm\infty$, so to say.

Comment: Right! This might be what I was missing. I was fixing that $\frac{1}{0}$ exponent like it was a constant value and instead only focusing on $x$ under the root, instead of considering the the exponent is actually *tending to* $\frac{1}{0}$, but isn't that number exactly. This probably explains everything.

Comment: @SamueleB.: recall that the expression $\frac10$ has no meaning and cannot be used in computations.

Comment: Surely, someone will come with the "extended real line" but this concept does not make $\frac{1}{0}$ meaningful either.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's the fallacy. For some reason, I failed to consider that a zeroeth root is akin to elevating to $\frac{1}{0}$ and has equally no meaning, outside of limits (in $\mathbb{R}$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{t\to0}\sqrt[t^2]2=\infty,$$

$$\lim_{t\to0}\sqrt[-t^2]2=0,$$

$$\lim_{t\to0}\sqrt[t]2\ \ \not\exists.$$